# Python Numpy: Radians to degrees in [0,360]

Tags: numpy, scipy

When applying `rad2deg`I get

```
>>> np.rad2deg(4*np.pi)
720.0
```

An angle of `720.0` degrees is in many application equivalent to an angle of `360.0` degrees.

What's the best way to convert radians (from `dtype=float64`) into degrees where the result is the correct value in `[0,180]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply modulo division:

```
result = converted % 360
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want [0,n]
Use

```
np.rad2deg(4*np.pi)%n
```